# how to equate the currency annual price of 2 different types of currency

Tags: r

I have an annual price dataset that has currency (USD, IDR). what if I want to change only the annual price with USD currency to IDR?

```
property['Annual_Price_new']=property['Annual_Price']
for (i in 1:length(property)){
    if(property['Currency'][i]=='USD'{
       property['Annual_Price_new'][i]=property['Annual_Price_new'][i]*14200
    }
}
```

That's my code but it is error

```
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"for (i in 1:length(property['Currency'][i]=='USD')){
  if(property['Currency'][i]=='USD'{"
```

Comment: The if statement is missing a ) after USD I believe

Comment: @RichardKYu  after i add a (, then error appears is Error in for (. in i) 1:length(property) : 
  4 arguments passed to 'for' which requires 3

Comment: @RichardKYu pointed out that you're missing a closing bracket (`)`) not an opening bracket (`(`).